# Contents changes when saving figure in different format using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png

Sometimes, I need to save my figure with `plt.savefig("./xxx.pdf")` or `plt.savefig("./xxx.png")`. Other than `png`file contain all the information of the plots, the **xlabel** and **ylabel** disappear in the `.pdf`file.

Here is an example. The plot code code are presented here.

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
fig,ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'),figsize = (10,6))
lon_grid  = np.linspace(x_map1,x_map2,len(x_grid))
lat_grid  = np.linspace(y_map1,y_map2,len(y_grid))
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(lon_grid,lat_grid)
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy,so2_mean,rstride = 1,cstride = 1,\
                cmap=plt.cm.Spectral_r,linewidth = 0)
ax.set_xticklabels(["114.2","114.4","114.6","114.8"])
plt.yticks(np.arange(37.7, 38.4, 0.2))
ax.set_yticklabels(["114.2","114.4","114.6","114.8"])
ax.set_zlabel(u'FOM'+ r'$\mathregular{(\mu g/m^3)}$',rotation = 90,fontsize = 14)
ax.set_xlabel(u'lon',fontsize = 14),ax.set_ylabel(u'lat',fontsize = 14)

ax.view_init(azim=-55,elev =35)

plt.autoscale(False)
ax.scatter(site_s.LON,site_s.LAT,site_s.CONC+2,marker= '^',color = "k",s = 50)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("./Fig/Fig.pdf")
plt.savefig("./Fig/Fig.png")
plt.show()
```

The `Fig.pdf` shows like this:

[image]

The `Fig.png` shows like this:
[image]

**The xlabel and ylabel are missing in pdf file**

Comment: Does `plt.savefig('xxx.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')` help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It doesn't work.

Comment: It might be the DPI issue. Try: `fig.savefig("./Fig/Fig.pdf", dpi=fig.dpi)`

Comment: Sorry for reply late. It doesn't work, too.